# Node js data retention

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

There are two forms on a single page, one for sending data and the other for entering pieces when clicking on the product.
That is, when I click on the product, a modal opens and I enter the number there, but I do not want the data in this modal to be sent immediately, I want it to be sent with the product information, how can I do that.

I am using mongodb as database.

Comment: Did you try with a global variable in javascript?

Comment: How can I do this I don't know how to run node js code inside script files

Comment: Share us your stack. Forms are in the client side. I meant vanilla javascript not nodejs. As you said, nodejs is for backend. Your problem in the frontend

Comment: I tried to solve it in a different way, it was solved thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.